# Jquery with HTML replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created and if else statement to reflect appropriate specific text, I have a Jfiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/heykate/osvg4h33/

What I am trying to accomplish, is depending if a user is logged in or not the text will change from Sign In or Create Account *(if Welcome Guest)* or say Sign Out *(if logged in, ie: Welcome Friend)*.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="welcome"> Welcome Guest <span class="acctLink"> </span></div>
<div class="welcome"> Welcome Friend <span class="acctLink"> </span></div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
if ($('.welcome:contains("Guest")').length > 0) 
{
    $("span.acctLink").html("Sign In Or Create An Account");
}
else
{
    $('span.acctLink').html("Sign out"); 
}
```

In JSFiddle, it is validating the script, but the parenthesis' around the else statement are highlighted green.

---

Follow Up

Thanks guys for the help I was able to get the jquery to work just as expected, and how I needed it to work. Again, thank you for all the help, here is my final solution (probably a better way to do this - feedback is always welcomed):

HTML:

```
<div class="welcome">Welcome %%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%% (<span class="customerMenu"> </span>)</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.welcome').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':contains("Guest")')) {
        $(this).find("span.customerMenu").html('<a href="/login.php">Sign In<a/> Or <a href="/login.php?action=create_account">Create An Account</a>');
    } else {
        $(this).find('span.customerMenu').html('<a href="/login.php?action=logout">Sign out</a>');

    }
});
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Logic error is likely the culprit.

Comment: it works, just library is not set in jsfiddle for jquery

Comment: Well, you haven't actually included jQuery in the fiddle. It's over on the left under "Frameworks & Extensions."  Also, the green parentheses/braces just mean that your cursor is touching them.

Comment: First thing first. The green is just an indicator when your cursor is after the parentheses to tell you where it start (or end). 2: jQuery is not loaded, maybe you can debug it if you see what's happening : http://jsfiddle.net/osvg4h33/4/

Comment: Kate - Is there really a problem with the script, or are you just concerned about the green brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking this:

```js
$(".welcome").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':contains("Guest")')) { //check if element with class welcome contains Guest text
        $(this).children("span").html("Sign In Or Create An Account");//find span element and change the text
    } else {
        $(this).children("span").html("Sign out");//here change span text if div with class welcome doesn't contains Guest text
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome">Welcome Guest <span class="acctLink"> </span>

</div>
<div class="welcome">Welcome Kate <span class="acctLink"> </span>

</div>
```

References:

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check out those links you provided.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('.welcome').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':contains("Guest")'))
    {
        $(this).find("span.acctLink").html("Sign In Or Create An Account");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('span.acctLink').html("Sign out"); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/osvg4h33/11/

Also you had not `jQuery` library contained

Comment: Thanks George! I pulled it directly off the site and put it in JSFiddle, sorry I missed that, and thanks for spotting it. Sometimes you just need an extra set of eye :)